# Azure : Point to Site, from the Certificate Authority, what kind of certificates should be requested?

Tags: ssl, azure-virtual-network, azure-vpn

As a part of the POC, I followed the article https://www.ais.com/how-to-configure-point-to-site-vpn-connection-using-azure-certificate-authentication/ and configured Point-to-Site.

**In summary:** I have created the Root & Client Certificate and configured the Virtual Gateway

Here we are generating the root certificate

```
$cert = New-SelfSignedCertificate -Type Custom -KeySpec Signature  -Subject "CN=VPNRoot" -KeyExportPolicy Exportable  -HashAlgorithm sha256 -KeyLength 2048  -CertStoreLocation "Cert:\CurrentUser\My" -KeyUsageProperty Sign -KeyUsage CertSign
```

Here we are generating the client certificate from the root certificate

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -Type Custom -DnsName VPNCert -KeySpec Signature  -Subject "CN=VPNCert" -KeyExportPolicy Exportable  -HashAlgorithm sha256 -KeyLength 2048  -CertStoreLocation "Cert:\CurrentUser\My" -Signer $cert -TextExtension @("2.5.29.37={text}1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2")
```

Now that it works, my goal is to replace the certificates ("Root" and "Client") with production ready certificates.

From the Certificate Authority, what kind of certificates should be requested?

**Note:** Our Azure Tenant is something like xyznp.onmicrosoft.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that In Azure Point to Site, you can use a root certificate that was generated using an Enterprise solution, or you can generate a self-signed certificate.

[image]

Refer :  [About Azure Point-to-Site VPN connections - Azure VPN Gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/point-to-site-about#authenticate-using-native-azure-certificate-authentication)

When you are using the enterprise solution certificate chain in the root certificate, you should acquire the `.cer file` for the root certificate that want to use.

And generate a client certificate with the common name value format  **`name@yourdomain.com`**. In your case it should be in the format **`xyznp@onmicrosoft.com`**

Refer : [Connect to a VNet using P2S VPN & certificate authentication: portal - Azure VPN Gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-point-to-site-resource-manager-portal#generatecert)

**NOTE** : Verify the authentication order on the client certificate if you used a certificate that was issued by an Enterprise CA solution and but having trouble for authenticating.

- By double-clicking the client certificate, choosing the **Details** tab, and then selecting **Enhanced Key Usage**, you can verify the authentication list order like below.

[image]

Make sure Client Authentication is listed first. If it isn't, create a client certificate based on the user template with Client Authentication listed as the first item.

Refer:   [Connect to a VNet using P2S VPN & certificate authentication: portal - Azure VPN Gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-point-to-site-resource-manager-portal#connect)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed information. How do I generate the enterprise certification and it's client certificate, can you please share the steps